# I am writing a service agreement, how do I cite a legal code in the agreement?

Tags: contract-law, california, towing, legal-citation

I am writing a service agreement, how do I cite a legal code in the agreement? As a company, I need to state what we will do and what the law requires us to do This is the law: [cvc 22658](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=22658&highlight=true&lawCode=VEH&keyword=notify)

(m) (1) A towing company that removes a vehicle from private property under this section shall notify the local law enforcement agency of that tow after the vehicle is removed from the private property and is in transit.

(2) A towing company is guilty of a misdemeanour if the towing company fails to provide the notification required under paragraph (1) within 60 minutes after the vehicle is removed from the private property and is in transit or 15 minutes after arriving at the storage facility, whichever time is less.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I cite a legal code in the agreement?

Saying "*section 22658 of the California Vehicle Code*" or "*Vehicle Code section 22658*" would work. See, for instance, [*Coffey v. Shiomoto*, 60 Cal.4th 1198 (2015)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/incaco20150406019) ("*pursuant to Vehicle Code section 13382*").

Comment: "California Vehicle Code § 22658" would also be acceptable. If there was any doubt regarding the version of the code that applied you could also state "California Vehicle Code § 22658 (2022)." (you might even need to be more specific about the date if it was amended mid-year).